# ASP.NET MVC2 - Custom Model Binder Examples

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, modelbinders, custom-model-binder

I am trying to find some examples of building a custom model binder for a unique binding scenario I need to handle, but all of the articles I found were for older versions of MVC which are no longer relevant in MVC2. I've been referencing the DefaultModelBinder source code to try to get a general feel for what I need to do, but it's entirely more complicated than my scenario and I'm having trouble isolating the specific logic I need to implement.

My goal is to take a collection of Checkbox/Textbox pairs and for all of the Checked pairs I would like to create a key/value pair of the Checkbox's value and the associated Textbox's value. After aggregating this data I need to do some string serialization on the collection so I can store it in a string property of the desired Model type. I already the data being sent from the form in a manageable format which will allow me to relate a given Checkbox to a specific Textbox, it's just a matter of figuring out how to get all the pieces where I need them.

Does anyone know of some up-to-date tutorials that can get me started with building a custom model binder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know why you think a lot has changed since MVC 1 regarding custom model binders. But If I understand what you are trying to do, it should be fairly easy.

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

        NameValueCollection form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
        //get what you need from the form collection

        //creata your model
        SomeModel myModel = new SomeMode();
        myModel.Property = "value";
        //or add some model errors if you need to
        ModelStateDictionary mState = bindingContext.ModelState;
        mState.Add("Property", new ModelState { });
        mState.AddModelError("Property", "There's an error.");

        return myModel; //return your model
    }
}
```

And your action :

```
public ActionResult Contact([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]SomeModel m){
    //...
}
```

Was that the kind of information you are looking for?

Comment: This technique totally works for me, but I was under the impression I should make use of the `bindingContext.ValueProvider` rather than accessing the HttpContext directly (for testability reasons).

Comment: @Nathan Taylor, I see. In that case, the technique described here might get you started. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx  
S. Hanselman also provides an example here about how to test the binder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253574/how-to-test-custom-model-binders-in-asp-net-mvc/589250#589250

Comment: Also, if you're looking for doing model binding based on a specific (or generic) type, check the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487005/asp-net-mvc-model-binder-for-generic-type

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at several examples of [Custom MVC Model binders](http://ivonna.biz/blog.aspx?filterby=Custom%20Asp.Net%20Model%20Binders%20for%20fun%20and%20profit) on my blog.

Comment: Website is down and the examples should be posted here - not an external site.