# Generic TimeSpan binding in Asp.NET MVC 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, timespan, modelbinders

I have an input form that is bound to a model. The model has a TimeSpan property, but it only gets the value correctly if I enter the time as hh:mm or hh:mm:ss. What I want is for it to capture the value even if it's written as hhmm or hh.mm or hh.mm.ss or ... I want many different formats to be parsed correctly. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - write a custom model binder for your model object. There's an thread about just that subject here on SO: [ASP.NET MVC2 - Custom Model Binder Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343913/asp-net-mvc2-custom-model-binder-examples)

Answer (score 22):

I added a few enhancements to Carles' code and wanted to share them here in case they're useful for others.

- Ensure that if no patterns successfully parse the time, then still call the base in order to show a validation error (otherwise the value is left as `TimeSpan.Zero` and no validation error raised.)
- Use a loop rather than chained `if`s.
- Support the use of `AM` and `PM` suffices.
- Ignore whitespace.

Here's the code:

```
public sealed class TimeSpanModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private const DateTimeStyles _dateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault;

    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;

        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(TimeSpan?)) || propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(TimeSpan)))
        {
            var text = form[propertyDescriptor.Name];
            TimeSpan time;
            if (text != null && TryParseTime(text, out time))
            {
                SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, time);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Either a different type, or we couldn't parse the string.
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }

    public static bool TryParseTime(string text, out TimeSpan time)
    {
        if (text == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

        var formats = new[] {
            "HH:mm", "HH.mm", "HHmm", "HH,mm", "HH",
            "H:mm", "H.mm", "H,mm",
            "hh:mmtt", "hh.mmtt", "hhmmtt", "hh,mmtt", "hhtt",
            "h:mmtt", "h.mmtt", "hmmtt", "h,mmtt", "htt"
        };

        text = Regex.Replace(text, "([^0-9]|^)([0-9])([0-9]{2})([^0-9]|$)", "$1$2:$3$4");
        text = Regex.Replace(text, "^[0-9]$", "0$0");

        foreach (var format in formats)
        {
            DateTime value;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _dateTimeStyles, out value))
            {
                time = value.TimeOfDay;
                return true;
            }
        }
        time = TimeSpan.Zero;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This may seem a little over the top, but I want my users to be able to enter pretty much anything and have my app work it out.

It can be applied to all `DateTime` instances via this code in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeSpan), new TimeSpanModelBinder());
```

Or just on a specific action method parameter:

```
public ActionResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(TimeSpanModelBinder))] MyModel model)
{ ... }
```

And here's a simple unit test just to validate some potential inputs/outputs:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TimeSpanParsing()
    {
        var testData = new[] {
            new { Text = "100", Time = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "10:00 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "2", Time = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "10", Time = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "100PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1000", Time = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "10:00", Time = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "10.00", Time = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "13:00", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "13.00", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "10 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "  10\t PM ", Time = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "10PM", Time = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1 am", Time = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1 AM", Time = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1 pm", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "01 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "0100 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "01.00 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "01.00PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1:00PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "1:00 PM", Time = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
            new { Text = "12,34", Time = new TimeSpan(12, 34, 0) },
            new { Text = "1012PM", Time = new TimeSpan(22, 12, 0) },
        };

        foreach (var test in testData)
        {
            try
            {
                TimeSpan time;
                Assert.IsTrue(TimeSpanModelBinder.TryParseTime(test.Text, out time), "Should parse {0}", test.Text);
                if (!Equals(time, test.Time))
                    Assert.Fail("Time parse failed.  Expected {0} but got {1}", test.Time, time);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Assert.Fail("Received format exception with text {0}", test.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps someone out.

Comment: And with tests too? Brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @Ted, you're welcome. Sometimes tests make the best documentation.

Comment: More than sometimes, because among many other things, we usually keep our tests up-to-date while there's no guarantee the documentation will be. If the tests work, then the "real documentation" is correct.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in MVC 5 because the BindProperty method never gets called.

Comment: @Mike, most likely you are binding to the wrong type. It should be something like this in `Global.asax.cs` : `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(<YOUR_MODEL_HERE>), new TimeSpanModelBinder());`

Comment: @DrewNoakes, Resharper says this line `propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(TimeSpan?))` should have been `propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == (typeof(TimeSpan?))` instead.

Comment: @RosdiKasim, does it say why? The code works as shown. It may be that `==` is not overloaded for `System.Type` and so R# says you can use the more natural operator syntax. I can't think of a reason to change it beyond that of style.

Comment: I think this question answers it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647808/resharper-suggestion-check-for-reference-equality-instead

Comment: @RosdiKasim Are you supposed to bind the `TimeSpan` or the `MyViewModel` in `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(<YOUR_MODEL_HERE>), new TimeSpanModelBinder())`? The examples all show binding `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @Jack In this case it should be `TimeSpan`, now I couldn't think of reason why I suggested `YOUR_MODEL_HERE`. Just remember if you bind `TimeSpan` you might want to bind `TimeSpan?` too... depends on your use case of course.

Comment: @Jack @Mike If you want bind property to get called you need this `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(<YOUR_MODEL_HERE>), new TimeSpanModelBinder())` to Global.asax.cs. If you want this to work for all TimeSpans then you need to change the code to override BindModel instead of BindProperty then add `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeSpan), new TimeSpanModelBinder());` to Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 3):

For the record, here's how I did it:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Utils.ModelBinders
{
    public class CustomTimeSpanModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;

            if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(TimeSpan?)))
            {
                var text = form[propertyDescriptor.Name];
                DateTime value;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
                        SetProperty(controllerContext,bindingContext,propertyDescriptor,value.TimeOfDay);
                else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
                    SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value.TimeOfDay);
                else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
                    SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value.TimeOfDay);
                else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "HH,mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
                    SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value.TimeOfDay);
                else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
                    SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value.TimeOfDay);
            }
            else
            {
                base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code.  Could you also show how you specified it to be used?  Can you configure this just for a single property on a particular model, or does it apply globally to all `TimeSpan` property binding operations?

Comment: I added this to the Application_Start method of the Global_asax.cs file: ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomTimeSpanModelBinder(); I think you can also specify this on an action by action basis using annotations.

Comment: Thanks Carles.  I've posted my adaptation of your code as an answer too.  In my case I wanted to handle as many different time-of-day strings as could reasonably be provided and interpreted.