# Resharper suggestion: check for reference equality instead

Tags: c#, resharper, equality

I don't understand why Resharper suggest me to "check for reference equality instead" in this code:

```
if ( typeToTranslate.Equals( typeof(string) ) )
{
    //do something
}
```

Why this should be better:

```
typeToTranslate == typeof(string)
```

------------EDIT------------

This is the method stub:

```
protected IType TranslateType(Type typeToTranslate)
{
    if (typeToTranslate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("typeToTranslate");

    //do some stuff

    if (typeToTranslate.Equals(typeof(string)))
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
    //return some stuff
 }
```

Comment: My Resharper doesn't suggest this?

Comment: @Thomas I use version 7.0.1

Comment: Is `typeToTranslate` actually a `Type` object, and not some other type?

Comment: @Servy It is a Type object: i added a more comprehensive code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234009/c-sharp-type-comparison-type-equals-vs-operator (accepted answer links an article which explains this pretty well)

Comment: Why don't you ask this question at the JetBrains Resharper forum? http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper

Comment: why downvote? please explain so I can improve my question...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Object.Equals` is a more general kind of equality than reference equality: if `x == y` then `x.Equals(y)`, but the converse isn't necessarily true. However, as documented in [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx):

> A **Type** object that represents a type is unique; that is, two **Type** object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of **Type** objects using reference equality.

Because ReSharper categorizes the "Check for reference equality instead" inspection option under "Common Practices and Code Improvements", my guess is that ReSharper is letting you know that it *suffices* to use reference equality to compare types; you don't need the more general kind of equality implied by the `Equals` method (even though for types the two are equivalent).

Answer (score 16):

From the [System.Type documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

> A Type object that represents a type is unique; that is, two Type
>   object references refer to the same object if and only if they
>   represent the same type. This allows for comparison of Type objects
>   using reference equality.

This means that `"string".GetType()` and `typeof(string)` return the *same reference*.  There is only a single instance of the System.Type object for System.String within an AppDomain.

As to why ReSharper says it's "better" to use `==` instead of `.Equals()`?  My guess is because `==` is more efficient and does not risk throwing a `NullReferenceException` if `typeToTranslate` were null (in your case).

Comment: I check that typeToTranslate is not null so it could be only for efficiency

Comment: @giammin : that's enough for R# to suggest!

Comment: The suggestion also appears if you write `Equals(typeToTranslate, typeof(string))`, so it's unlikely that `NullReferenceException` is the reason.

Comment: @Michael -- Fair enough.  Unfortunately, R# doesn't have a "why is resharper suggesting this?" entry for this particular suggestion.  It would be good to hear their reasoning.  To me, it makes some intuitive sense to "prefer" == and reference equality, if possible, as reference equality is a simpler operation.